# How to convert file to base64Binary in android?

Tags: android

Below code is for convert file to bytearray.

```
 public static byte[] convertFileToByteArray(File f) {
    byte[] byteArray = null;
    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] b = new byte[1024 * 8];
        int bytesRead = 0;

        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(b)) != -1) {
            bos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        byteArray = bos.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return byteArray;
}
```

But I need a code for convert file to binary format.

Comment: A byte array is binary already. What do you want exactly?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

Get your byte array file:

```
File file= new File("path file");
byte[] fileByte=convertFileToByteArray(file);
```

Then convert to base64 in byte array:

```
byte[] file_in_base64 = Base64.encode(fileByte, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Convert byte array to binary:

```
String toBinary( byte[] bytes )
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.length * Byte.SIZE);
    for( int i = 0; i < Byte.SIZE * bytes.length; i++ )
        sb.append((bytes[i / Byte.SIZE] << i % Byte.SIZE & 0x80) == 0 ? '0' : '1');
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: look I changed my answer there if that's what you want

Comment: `Convert byte array to binary:`. No. That converts a byte array to a String.

Comment: `I done with base64 but i want to convert base64binary format`. Sorry but i do not undferstand what you want. `file_in_base64` is a byte array already and as binary as can be.

Comment: @Ludger Thanks for the code..Getting out of memory exception while posting binary data to server using JsonStringer in asynctask. Please suggest me.

Comment: the Binary that there mentioned is to convert the byte to 0 and 1 but because Strings in java byte array can be: byte [] exampleByte = new byte [] {0x42, 0x69, 0x10, 0x0d};